# Look behind Regex for updating mariaDB column

Tags: regex, mariadb

I'm trying to write a look behind regex to select the string from MariaDB column

```html
<div class="class1">
  <div class="class2">
    <span>
      <a title="Search for Product" href="${firstProductLink}/product/product.html">Search for product
      </a>
    </span>
    <span>
      <a title="Search for Product"  href="${firstProductLink}/sample/sample.html">Search for sample
      </a>
    </span>
    <span>
      <a title="Search for Product" href="${secondProductLink}/product/product.html">Search for 
    product
      </a>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is a value in the column of my table. I'm writing a regex that could get anchor tag with firstProductLink in href and replace it to empty like below

```xml
<div class="class1">
  <div class="class2">
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span>
      <a title="Search for Product" href="${secondProductLink}/product/product.html">Search for 
    product
      </a>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thinking of using MariaDB method REGEXP_REPLACE (column, (regex), '').

Regex I tried -> `(?<=\firsinsuranceLink)` -> But this is not working.

Can someone help me with writing regex for the above?

Comment: What version of MariaDB are you using? PCRE support was added in 10.0.5.

Comment: Why do you need a lookbehind for this? You want to include `firsinsuranceLink` in the match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a lookbehind for this, since the word is included in what you want to match and replace.

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(columnname, '<span>
 *<a.*firstProductLink.*
 *</a>
 *</span>', '')
```

Comment: I removed the `$` character, it has special meaning in regexp.

Comment: You need newlines in the regexp: https://regex101.com/r/hg6ytx/2 Also, regex101 requires you to escape `/` characters, but that shouldn't be needed in MySQL.

Comment: It worked fine Barmar. I learned regex today Hope I can help someone in the future.